# Simple dom php parse get custom data attribute value

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

HTML:

```
<div class="something" data-a="abc">ddsf</d>
```

PHP:

```
foreach ($dom->find('.something[data-rel]') as $this) {
    var_dump($this->attr());
}
```

I tried this but error. Couldn't find any info on its documentation. I want to get the `data-a`'s value which is abc.

Comment: Your code makes no sense at all, you probably want to do this with javascript.

Comment: @JelleKeizer why? If u wonder why 1 element need a foreach, actually that is just an example

Comment: the question is straight to the point, how to get custom data attribute value in simple php dom parser.

Comment: Sorry was misreading it, did you try getAttribute('data-a');

Answer (score 6):

Why not just use the well-documented, built in, [DOM extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)?

#### Example:

```
$html = '<div class="something" data-a="abc">ddsf</div>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$nodes = $xpath->query('//div[@class="something"]/@data-a');
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    var_dump($node->value);
}
```

#### Output:

```
string(3) "abc"
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this:

```
$dom->find('div[data-a]',0)->{'data-a'}
```

Comment: how bout $dom->find('div[data-a]')->{'data-a'} ? the zero is optional right? because assume I can do like this 
$dom->find('.panel [data-a]')->{'data-a'}

Comment: No, the 0 means the first match. Without the 0 you get an array.

Comment: I couldn't for the life of me find this in the docs. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

use

```
foreach($html->find('button') as $element) 
   echo $element->{'data-coupon'};
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php)

Should be something like this:

```
foreach ($dom->xpath('/div[@data-a]') as $item) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: are you sure? this is like getting the right element, is this the way u get the value the custom attr?

Comment: No, this way you find and loop through all 'div' elements that have "data-a" attribute. To get the value of this attribute you just need to access $item->attributes()->{'data-a'}